# remove duplicate dates, and matain the last

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

i have a json object that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    x:Tue Jan 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)
    y:80
  }
  {
    x:Tue Jan 17 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)
    y:78
  }
  {
    x:Tue Jan 17 2017 15:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)
    y:63
  }
  {
    x:Tue Jan 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)
    y:80
  }
]
```

in this case i just want the last 2 items, i dont want the day 17 Jan before the last, i want the last related to each day, how can i do this approach with jquery?

Comment: `arr.slice(0, -1)`

Comment: i have more days, this is just a example, it can change depending on a filter, i want a general function that does the job removing duplicate dates and mantain the last of each day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a temporary object where the dates are the object keys, then map that object to array.

During each iteration of setting the object property; if that date already existed it will simply get overwritten with the last one in array

```
var tmp = {};

data.forEach(function(item){
   var d = new Date(item.x);
   var yr = d.getFullYear(),
       mo = d.getMonth(),
       day = d.getDate();

   tmp[yr +'' + mo + '' + day] = item; // will overwrite prior same date
});

var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(funcion(key){
    return tmp[key];
});
```

This assumes that the ones you want are determined by last order in existing

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) to parse and convert each date and loop through the array in the reverse order. The data already in the resulting array will be skipped.

The snippet:

```js
var data = [
  {
    x: 'Tue Jan 17 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)',
    y: 80
  },
  {
    x: 'Tue Jan 17 2017 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)',
    y: 78
  },
  {
    x: 'Tue Jan 17 2017 15:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)',
    y: 63
  },
  {
    x: 'Tue Jan 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Hora padrão de GMT)',
    y: 80
  }
];
var eleAlreadyInserted = {};
var resultData = [];
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var ddyy = moment(data[i].x, 'ddd MMM DD YYY').format('DDYYYY');
  if (eleAlreadyInserted[ddyy] === undefined) {
    eleAlreadyInserted[ddyy] = true;
    resultData.unshift(data[i]);
  }
}

console.log(resultData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: really need a date library just for trivial date parsing?

Comment: @charlietfl No it's not necessary by itself. Thank you so much